# Which ship has made the most first contacts?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-tos, star-trek-enterprise

From what we see in *Star Trek*, first contacts are *very* important dealings.  So, my question is **which ship <sup>1</sup> has made the most number of first contacts?**

Allow me to define 'first contacts'.  For the *Enterprise* NX-01, I define a first contact as a meeting with an alien species that humans had not previously made official contact with (for example, the meeting with the Klingons in the second episode would count as a first contact).  For the *Enterprise* 1701 and 1701-D, and *Voyager*, these must be species that the *Federation* has not yet encountered.

<sup>1</sup>: By ship, I'm restricting it to the *Enterprises* NX-01, NCC-1701 and NCC-1701-D and *Voyager*, as they're likely to have made the most on-screen.

Comment: My hunch is either Voyager or the original Enterprise.

Comment: Restriction futile. Borg Cube is superior.

Comment: I'm sure I've read a question like this before but I can't find s the dupe...

Comment: You don't want to count DS9 or the _Defiant_, with all their Gamma Quadrant first contacts?

Comment: @OftenRight: I need some clarification, you define 'first contact' as a meeting with an _alien culture_ for the Enterprise NX-01 and for the other ships a _species not yet encountered_. The Neural Parasites and the Space Amoeba encountered in TOS would not be an _alien culture_ but would be a _new species not yet encountered_ for example.  I think you are asking for two different things

Comment: @sfhq_sf I can see how it could be interpreted that way; sloppy wording on my part.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the list maintained at Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/First_contacts), the stats are as follows:

- NX-01: 27
- 1701: 50 (49 with Kirk's crew, 1 with Pike's)
- 1701-D: 41
- DS9 / Defiant: 13
- **Voyager: 107**

Please note that I counted any first contacts that involve the main cast of the relevant series, whether it took place on that series's ship or not.  (For example, Riker meeting the young alien who made him think he'd had 30 years worth of amnesia.  It happened on a planet, not on the 1701-D, but I counted it)

Also, these numbers are assuming I counted correctly while scrolling.

Comment: All those statistics other than DS9 would be valid for the purposes of this question. Good find!

Comment: Consider it bonus information. Plus it doesn't impact the actual answer, as "the most" is still clearly Voyager by a long shot.

Comment: Technicality: this only counts first contacts shown or reported on the show.

Comment: I hardly think this is a fair comparison. Voyager had many more episodes :-)

Comment: @OrangeDog How else would we count them?

Comment: @Xantec there may be a separate source reporting the count (rather than viewer extrapolation), or you do what Richard did.

Answer (score 11):

According to the Season 7 episode [VOY: Friendship One](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/718.htm) James Kirk, and by extension, the NCC-1701 Enterprise still remains the **undisputed** champion of first contacts, with Janeway coming in second aboard the Voyager.

> **HENDRICKS** [on screen]: *The Voth, the Kobali, the Vaadwaur. **You've made first contact with more species than any captain since James Kirk.***
>
> **JANEWAY:** *It helps being the only Starfleet ship within thirty thousand light years.*
>
> **HENDRICKS** [on screen]: *You are being too humble. From the first time you spoke up in my classroom I knew you'd go far.*

It seems unlikely the she surpassed his record in the final few episodes

Comment: Technicalities: this confirms the captain, not the ship. It also doesn't preclude someone earlier (e.g. Archer) scoring higher than Janeway but lower than Kirk.

Comment: @OrangeDog - True, but in his latter years, Kirk was chained to a desk. It hardly seems likely that he was doing much first-contacting from Starfleet HQ.

Comment: True, but equally he's been on a lot more ships than just the original NCC-1701, even if a lot of them did explode shortly after.

Comment: It is possible the Hendricks was just talking up Janeway by comparing her to a famous captain who had a lot of first contacts. An exo-zoologist on Europa might get to categorize a lot of new life forms, and someone might compare them to Louis and Clark without knowing exactly how many species of fauna they catalogued.

Comment: @OftenRight:   I dare say this answer is superior to the currently accepted answer.   The currently accepted one is only counting whatever was shown (or mentioned) in the shows/movies, whereas this is a canon statement that Kirk has more than Janeway.    You should accept this one.   You can nitpick about captain vs ship etc, but it's pretty clear this statement is 98% likely to mean NCC-1701/1701A have more contacts than Voyager.